# calculating the determinant of an $n \times n$ integer matrix

Tags: matrices, computational-complexity

I want to write a polynomial algorithm for calculating the determinant of an $n \times n$ integer matrix. There are various codes in different programming languages on the web but unfortunately I am not good at understanding codes which are written by other people. Normally, what steps will it take to calculate the determinant of an $n \times n$ integer matrix, then I can write the algorithm and compute its time complexity on my own.

Comment: Laplace expansion is a method for calculating the determinant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion

Comment: Laplace expansion works but it will take exponential time.  For a more efficient method, take the (possibly negated) product of the diagonal entries of the triangular factor in the Hermite decomposition.  Strange that it's difficult to find references to this method on the web.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One method is to use Gaussian elimination to reduce the matrix to upper triangular form.  The determinant is then the product of the diagonal matrix elements.  The problem with this method when matrix elements are integers is that Gaussian elimination will produce fractions in general.  For large matrices, the denominators of these fractions can blow up rather fast.

One way around this is to work modulo a prime, $p$.  This is equivalent to working over the finite field $\mathbf{F}_p.$  Since division can be performed in a finite field, you don't have to worry about the fraction problem.  Of course the answer you obtain will only be correct modulo $p.$  If you happen to know that your determinant is between $0$ and $p,$ then you're done at this point.  Hadamard's determinant bound can be used to place an upper bound on the absolute value of the answer.  If this upper bound is $h,$ then as long as $p>2h,$ you will be able to recover the answer.  (You need $2h$ because the answer might be negative.)

Hadamard's bound also gets big very quickly, and most of the time is far bigger than the actual determinant, which means that you may have to use a $p$ that is impractically large.  An alternative is to perform the calculation modulo several primes $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ whose product is larger than $2h.$  The Chinese remainder theorem can then be used to reconstruct the answer.

A different method is to use Dodgson condensation.  All of these suggestions are taken form Henri Cohen's book, *A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory*, which I highly recommend.  If this isn't enough detail to get you started, let me know, and I'll try to expand on this answer.

Comment: Nice answer! +1

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. Do you have the pdf version of the book so that I can read the part you've recommended or should I buy it from amazon? And could you please talk about the time complexity of each method a bit?

Comment: Never mind the last bit of my question, I am doing it on my own now and it's quite straightforward. Thank you.

Comment: Looking at Henri Cohen's webpage, it doesn't appear that the book is freely available, and I don't have an electronic copy myself.  The relevant section is very short, however (bottom of page 50 to top of page 53).  I was able to view all of these pages at Amazon, but you may have to have an Amazon account to do this.  I searched the book for "determinant".